# How to rotate an image upward and downward using javascript in mobile application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, mobile, rotation

Currently what I'm trying to do is rotate an image such as a chair or a table and when user

touch the image and drag upward or downward, they will be able to see the top and bottom of

that chair or table. Can someone give me a solution or any reference which can help me to

fulfill this task? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery Mobile (I'm assuming you are because of the tags you applied to your post), try to play with Touch events. Specifically, try `taphold`.

[jQuery mobile >](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html)

Answer (score 0):

For the touch and drag, you can use touchstart/touchmove/touchend events. You can easily find documents of touch events from Apple's developer website. Both iOS and Android support touch events.

Because touch and drag is a gesture, you might want to see if there is any library implemented this gesture. A gesture is a combination of touches with restrictions. Of course you can define a gesture with touch events and a lot of JavaScript code, but it would be easier to reuse what's been written and tested by others. See if you can find anything useful in jQuery Mobile, Sencha, or Pointer.js.

Image rotation can be done with CSS3 transform. You can easily get information about transform property from Apple's developer website or just a Google search. Use 3D transform instead of 2D when available, because in most devices 3D transform is hardware accelerated while 2D is not.